# Android Broadcastreceiver not working?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use a broadcastreceiver to capture a network change but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

My broadcastreceiver:

```
public class btReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public btReceiver() {

}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("BB","Received!");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Action: " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
}
```

The way I call it:

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(getPackageName() + "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

    btReceiver myReceiver = new btReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

But when I try to toggle let's say wifi, nothing happens at all. I also tried declaring it in the manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".btReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
         </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But that also doesn't work.

I have declared sufficient permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My test device is running Android 7.1.1, does anyone know why it's not firing?

Answer (score 0):

Your package name shouldn't be part of the `Intent` action. So try with:

```
filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
```

Even better, there's a constant for that:

```
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps targeting Android `N (Nougat)` do not receive `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcasts, even if they have manifest entries to request notification of these events. Apps that are running can still listen for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` on their main thread if they request notification with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

You should register it programmatically or use `JobScheduler`, `GcmNetworkManager` or [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library

Comment: This is true, though he is registering the `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically, which is legal. He probably added the receiver in the manifest to make it work, which is pointless since it's trying to intercept the wrong `Intent` action